# Bug with timeline in videojs

Tags: javascript

I have bug with timeline in videojs player. When I click in timeline to any time, for example 10:00 then player turn this time in 10:10 or 10:11. In general when I click, In general, when I click on any place in the timeline, it adds an additional 10-11 seconds to it and it happens when you double-click. But on the phone this bug works without double clicking. What could be the problem, who knows? It will be difficult to upload the player code because it is large, but maybe someone has encountered this bug and knows its solution.

I tried to fix the bug, and only managed to fix it on one click. If a person clicks several times, the bug happens again, but on phone it didn't help at all.

Comment: Are you referring to the `video.js` NPM package? If so, this might be better raised on their GitHub following their process for raising issues: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues

Make sure there isn't an existing issue already raised first.

Comment: Yes, I referring to the video.js  I know their github, but there is absolutely no user support there at all. There are a lot of bugs in the player, but developers don't respond to these bugs and don't want to fix them, so I decided to write here. I already created a topic about another bug there earlier, and I as well as other users were just ignored